# Lua execute windows command in Lightroom SDK

Tags: lua, sdk, lightroom

I’m porting my lightroom plugin to Windows. On MacOSX everything works perfect.

Now i’m stuck with one command, Normally I try to use as mutch of LR commands because they are compatible with both OS’s.

```
cmdRunExifTool = string.format('cd "'..NewTargetDir..'"  &&  '.._PLUGIN.path..'\\bin\\win\\exiftool.exe '..(optionOverwrite or "")..' optionAppend=".\\C+F-'..NewJson..'" .') 
LrTasks.execute(cmdRunExifTool)
```

I have added a pop-up window with the command and it show me this:

```
cd "c:\Users\patri\Pictures\TEST-IMAGES\FF690-KTMX-000869\_scans\positives\C+F_exiftool" && c:\Users\patri\Documents\AnalogeFotografie.lrplugin\bin\win\exiftool.exe optionAppend=".\C+F-mybeelden" .
```

But nothing happens.
If I run this on the command line it works !

Comment: Try `cmdRunExifTool = 'cmd /c "'..cmdRunExifTool..'"'` before executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For WIN_ENV you have to surround the whole cmdline with double-quotes (")

```
function cmdlineQuote()
    if WIN_ENV then
        return '"'
    elseif MAC_ENV then
        return ''
    else
        return ''
    end
end

cmdRunExifTool = 
    cmdlineQuote() .. 
    string.format('cd "'..NewTargetDir..'"  &&  '.._PLUGIN.path..'\\bin\\win\\exiftool.exe '..(optionOverwrite or "")..' optionAppend=".\\C+F-'..NewJson..'" .')  ..
    cmdlineQuote()
LrTasks.execute(cmdRunExifTool)
```

Comment: So I have created the string in single quotes, and then wrapped in double quotes (cmdlineQuote().
For being save in MacOSX I do the reverse ? the string in double quotes and then cmdlineQuote() single quote

Comment: For MacOS you do not need quotes of any kind around the whole command: build the command as string as if you would enter it in a terminal. Another hint: using '/' in paths works also for Windows, nicer than '\\'.